# Cannot Import Models In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to import my models file into my api.py file but, I get this error:

```
> from dashboard.models import Customer, Lines, Devices
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dashboard'
```

My apps.py is:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class DashboardConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'dashboard'
```

My settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'dashboard'
]
```

My models:

```
from django.db import models


class Customer(models.Model
               ):
    account_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    accountNumber = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    accountType = models.CharField(default='', max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    allowDangerousExtensions = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billingCycleDay = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    @property
    def customer_name(self):
        return (self.account_name)
    
    
class Lines(models.Model):
    accountId = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    deviceName = models.CharField(default='', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    deviceTypeId = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.accountId()
    

class Devices(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    customer =  models.ForeignKey(Customer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name()
```

and api.py:

```
from dashboard.models import Customer, Lines, Devices
def create_customer():
customer = Customer.objects.create()
```

But I cannot reference the models in the api.py file. I can reference it in my Admin.py but, api.py does not work.

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: What is the path of the file named api.py?

Comment: I updated the question with a photo of the path

Answer (score 0):

You can import your classes (models) by typing this because they are in the same directory

```
from .models import Customer, Lines, Devices
```

or using them directly like this:

```
models.Lines # for example
```

Comment: I got this error: from .models import Customer, Lines, Devices
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an absolute import by specifying the full path to the model file in your project.

**As I can see your project name is "`Albion`"
So it should be like below:**

```
from Albion.dashboard.models import Customer, Lines, Devices
```

Comment: I tried that and got: from Albion.dashboard.models import Customer, Lines, Devices
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Albion'

Comment: Are you running django on venv? Could you please try rerun the server?